# Are these FabricUI components still supported and can i use them?

Tags: css, office-ui-fabric

I'm investing and trying out  some of these components in my web part (classic page)

**The Persona Card**

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/persona/persona
```

**Ref below**

```
https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css

https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css

https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js
```

And I assume they should be responsive but when I view them on my mobile phone they seem to keep overlapping other elements.
Any ideas on how to fix this and how to override the CSS to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the **Office UI Fabric** to work in a classic page, there are some "tricks" you have to pull with renaming the .css files.  Check out [this thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/can-i-use-office-ui-fabric-on-classic-wiki-pages/m-p/523689).

Comment: Thanks William for that.I tried it but no luck by changing the filename.One problem i noticed though is some icons work some dont.

For example 
<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Vacation"></i>
this doesn't work

but this does 
<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Phone"></i>

Any ideas?

Comment: All in took in my tenant was to make my own copy of the fabric.min.css and renamed to corpui.min.css in siteassets, then referenced the new file.

Comment: I'm not using the components.css, so you may have to do the same with that.

Comment: Thanks William but no luck..The ms icons work randomly. Can you provide the references fabric url you are using? Thanks

Comment: `/sites/pocsite/siteassets/corpui.min.css`

Comment: Keep in mind that the UI Fabric was intended for Modern Pages, so you have to jump through hoops to get it to work in Classic.

Comment: I mean the fabric ui css and js references..

Comment: That is my .css reference.  I downloaded https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css, renamed it to corpui.min.css, and uploaded to my siteassets library, and referenced that.  My js reference matches yours, I only had to do that trick with the css.

Comment: Thanks so muc WIllman. But where are you getting your Icon references from.I sit from here https://codepen.io/MistaTwist/pen/BoNLEG

Comment: It's the same file as Microsoft's, I just downloaded it and renamed it instead of referencing it on their CDN.

Comment: ok. I'm talking about this  :- Some icons work some dont. For example <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Vacation"></i> this doesn't work but this does <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Phone"></i>. Are you using the same class as i listed